# If $f\circ q,g\circ q$ are homotopic on $S^1$, are $f,g$ homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f,g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be continuous functions.

Define $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1:t\mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$.

If $f\circ \alpha$ and $g\circ \alpha$ are homotopic, then are $f,g$ homotopic?

How do I prove this?

Comment: Well [0,1] is contractible, so...

Comment: A homotopy between maps from a point is the same thing as a path. What can you say about paths between points in $S^1$?

Comment: IF you have two maps $f,g:X\to Y$ and either $X$ or $Y$ is contractable, then the maps are homotopic.

Comment: @Aaron provided $Y$ is path connected.

Comment: @MattS Yes.  I have a bad habit of assuming all spaces are path connected (and locally path connected and hausdorff and locally compact and...) unless I have a particular example that isn't.

Comment: Do you mean $f\circ \alpha$ and $g\circ \alpha$ are homotopic paths with respect to their end points? That would make more sense and is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that since $I$ is contractible and $S^1$ is connected, $f \circ \alpha, g \circ \alpha : I \to S^1$ are *always* going to be homotopic. A proof of this statement is included below.

However, if your statement is correct, it would follow that $f, g : S^1 \to S^1$ are always homotopic, which isn't true.

---

A space $X$ is contractible if the identity map $i_X : X \to X$ is nullhomotopic.

**Lemma**: If $X$ is contractible and $Y$ is path connected, then $f, g : X \to Y$ are homotopic.

**Proof**: Since $X$ is contractible, $i_X \simeq e_c$ for some $c \in X$.

So there exists a homotopy $H : X \times I \to X$ with $H(x, 0) = e_X(x) = x$ and $H(x, 1) = e_c(x) = c$.

Notice that $f \circ H$ is a homotopy between $f = f \circ i_X$ and $f \circ e_c = e_{f(c)}$. and $g \circ H$ is a homotopy between $g = g \circ i_X$ and $g \circ e_c = e_{g(c)}$.

Since $Y$ is path connected, there exists a path $\alpha : I \to Y$ with $\alpha(0) = f(c)$ and $\alpha(1) = g(c)$. This induces a homotopy between $e_{f(c)}$ and $e_{g(c)}$: Define $K : Y \times I \to Y$ by $K(s, t) = \alpha(t)$; observe that $K(s, 0) = \alpha(0) = f(c)$ and $K(s, 1) = \alpha(1) = g(c)$.

Hence we have $f \simeq e_{f(c)} \simeq e_{g(c)} \simeq g$.

Conclude that $f$ is homotopic to $g$.